# Create windows shortcut and download it in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a custom windows shortcut and download it in asp.mvc.
Specifically I want to be able to download a remote desktop shortcut with dynamic server as argument.

I came accross this example on the internet but in was clearly not meant for web application.

```
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
            WshShell wsh = new WshShell();
            IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut("/shorcut.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
            shortcut.Arguments = "";
            shortcut.TargetPath = "c:\\app\\myftp.exe";
            // not sure about what this is fro
            shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;
            shortcut.Description = "my shortcut description";
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\app";
            //shortcut.IconLocation = "specify icon location";
            shortcut.Save();

        return File("/shorcut.lnk", "application/octet-stream", "shorcut.lnk");
    }
```

I got a plain access is denied. Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Which line gave you the access denied error?

Answer (score 0):

I took the problem to the wrong direction, i did not need to do a shortcut to mstsc.exe but i needed to create my own rdp file that contains very simple text as a parameter.

```
public ActionResult Download()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string srv = "mysrv.myurl.com";
            sb.AppendFormat("full address:s:{0}", srv);
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()),
             "text/plain",
              string.Format("{0}.rdp", srv));
        }
```

This is working